# Unexpected behavior when reading two strings from cin and writing them back

Tags: c++

I am struck. In this program if input is:

```
11110000
11110000
```

Output should be:

```
11110000
11110000
```

but I am getting this as output instead:

```
 1110000
11110000
```

My code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char a[8];
    char b[8];
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cin >> b;

    for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
      std::cout << a[i];
    }

    std::cout << "\n";

    for (int j=0; j<8; j++) {
      std::cout << b[j];
    }
}
```

Comment: #offtopic: isn't the _most basic_ program supposed to be "hello world"?

Comment: HInt: rent-a-room for null-terminator.

Comment: Keep a space for your null value which will be end of line \0.
if the length of your string, or int is 8 give it one extra size and it should be 9, because there is always a null pointer at the end..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your program does not allocate enough memory to store both `a` and `b` input: in order to store 8 characters of text you need to allocate 9 `char`s - the last one is for C string's null terminator:

```
char a[9];
char b[9];
```

Currently, your program exhibit undefined behavior because of buffer overrun, which is easily the most common problem to be exploited by hackers.

Fortunately, this problem has a very easy fix: replacing `char` arrays with `std::string` lets your strings change capacity with the size of end-user's input, preventing buffer overruns:

```
std::string a;
std::string b;
```

You need to `#include <string>` in order to compile the modified code.

Comment: Thanks for replying and not voting down...i am new here n each questions of freshers are voted down...Why its not showing error in last input?

Comment: @Himanshu Short answer is that you got lucky. Long answer is that behavior is undefined: you are writing to some other space which may or may not be legitimately allocated to some other data structure, or used by a CPU instruction. If the other variable/structure is not touching that space, you get the result that looks OK; otherwise, you get result that looks wrong. You need to use a memory profiler tool, such as valgrind, to find hidden errors like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
char a[8];
char b[8];
cin>>a;
cin>>b;
```

If you enter more than 7 characters for `a`, it will overwrite into `b`, since `cin >> a;` will read in a C-style string that has a terminating `\0` at the end. Make it `char a[9]; char b[9];`, and assuming it's only 8 characters in the input, it will work fine.

Better yet, use `std::string` instead of fixed length C style strings, and you can enter as much as you like wihtout any trouble.